# Is it possible to have an error message appear around the cell of a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifydataerrorinfo

This question is a follow-up to one I [posted on SO yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645689/is-it-possible-to-show-the-error-message-entered-in-a-data-annotation-in-the-mod). I've followed Andy's suggestion to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. I've used it in the `Class` model class I referred yesterday. And I found an [article on C-SharpCorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tirthacs/inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf/) which I also adapted to my situation. After putting these in place and testing it, I found that it does catch the range restriction. However, it only circled the cell with the problem in the `DataGrid` in red. It didn't show me the error message next to the cell, which is what my boss wants. I'm wondering if what the boss wants isn't possible in a WPF `DataGrid`? Or have I botched it?

I set a breakpoint in the `HandleValidationResults` method from the second link above. It properly assigns the error message to the `_errors` collection. Here's how I modified the `DataGridTextColumn`:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:0000}, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="dataGridTextColumn" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the validation error template directly, set it in the `ElementStyle` or `EditingElementStyle`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                  <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="dataGridTextColumn" />
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
               </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

[image: DataGrid with occluding error template.]

However, you will notice that your current approach does not work well, as the error template will occlude other cells below the cell that is in error. A better alternative is to set the error  template as `ToolTip`. This way, the errors are shown as popup *if you hover over a cell in error*.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.(Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red" />
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl>
                  </ToolTip>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

[image: DataGrid column with error tool tip.]